# C# API method call throwing an exception

Tags: c#, html, xml, api, methods

I'm writing a Windows Form app that uses an API (the smartFOCUS API, to be precise) to write simple reports and write them to a file.

I've done this about a hundred times using another simple Windows Form app I wrote, and the calls works fine, but when I try it with the app I'm working on, it returns this exception on the call:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled.
Message = Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'
```

Any idea on what could be causing this exception? It's really confusing me.

If you'd like any more code or exception details or anything let me know.

Here's the code that calls the method:

```
        soap.GetEvents2(logOn.Username,
                        logOn.Password,
                        logOn.BoothKey,
                        flag,
                        ref eventFields,
                        this.EventCode,
                        accountKey,
                        emailKey,
                        packageKey,
                        replyMapKey,
                        this.BatchKey,
                        this.StartDate,
                        this.EndDate,
                        maxRows,
                        ref results);
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here's the reponse HTML:

```
The request failed with the error message:
--
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the messiness of that.

Comment: Hmm - it sounds like the server is blowing up and returning a generic HTML page instead of a SOAP/XML document.  Is there any way to examine the exception / client to see if it contains any of the response HTML?

Comment: @RQDQ Yep, the exception returns HTML of some description. I'll post it on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server is returning the SOAP response with the Content-Type header set to text/html, while the library requires content type text/xml.  So you need to change the configuration of your web server to serve the page as XML.

If the server is using ASP.NET, then a common cause of this would be because the web service encountered an error.  The error details are written as an HTML formatted page to the client, rather than a SOAP XML response.  If you can examine the raw output from the web service then you should be able to see an error message that will lead you to a solution.

**EDIT**

From the HTML you provided, this does indeed look like a generic error page.  It looks the server is configured to hide the error details. In ASP.NET you can enable this by adding the following to the web service's web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off">
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you don't control the web service then you might have to get help from the API provider - perhaps one of your input parameters is bad?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't completely understand your answer. Who do you mean by client?

Comment: Your client is whatever is calling the web service - so in your case the library API library supplied by the marketing company.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look into response? Receiving `html` instead of `xml` is usually a sign thay you did web-request to incorrect URL and received `404` error or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the smartFOCUS api you are using...

It appears that whatever endpoint you are hitting is responding with the wrong content type. As indicated by the exception the call is expecting a result with a content type of `text/xml` but is getting `text/html` (might be a valid soap message but the content type isn't set to xml explicitly).

I would recommend spinning up [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) or some other form of debugging/interacting with the service endpoint directly and seeing if the responses are valid, if you don't control the endpoint that is sending the inappropriate content type for the response you may want to contact whoever is in control and see if they can remedy the issue.

**EDIT** - Response to additional info in OP question.

Given the response posted it appears that the call is invalid, this could be due to a number of reasons; Incorrect parameters being passed and not handled correctly on the server, a completely invalid endpoint being referenced or genuine server problems out of your scope. If you are passing correct parameters to the correct endpoint then I would definitely suggest contacting the owner of the endpoint to get the situation resolved.. if you aren't sure I would also recommend again to try and debug the calls via [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) or some other endpoint interaction tool.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is happening on the server side.  Is there any kind of error logging available for the smartFocus API?  Is this a cloud service or is this a service that you host someplace?

Comment: It's not my service, no. It's a Marketing Company's API. I'm using it to build up my own reports.

Comment: In this case, you're likely stuck either guessing at what's wrong with your arguments / configuration or contacting the company and working with their support to determine what's happening.